# AngularJS Error: [$injector:itkn] Incorrect injection token! Expected service name as string, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying to run an Angular app containing this controller:

```
routerApp.controller('chartSettingsCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', 
 , function($scope, $timeout) { /* body omitted */ }
```

gives me the error:

```
Error: [$injector:itkn] Incorrect injection token! Expected service name as string, got undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Discussed here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339722/692942

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The actual problem is that I had an extra `,` in the controller. When I changed that, it worked.

**From**

```
routerApp.controller('chartSettingsCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout',
 , function($scope, $timeout) {
```

**To**

```
routerApp.controller('chartSettingsCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout',
 function($scope, $timeout) {
```

Comment: The fact that there are 45+ upvotes makes me feel a lot better about this one